# onclick window.location.href with variable

Tags: javascript, php, window.location

I have a select with some options inside and I want the user to be sent to another page with a variable in the URI so that I can extract it.

This is how my select is set up:

```
<select name="period" onclick="window.location.href = 'test.php?Period=' + this.selectedIndex;">
```

I should then be able to use $_GET['Period'] to get the value.

However, the user is never sent to test.php.

Why is this?

Comment: Well, where are they sent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select name="period" onchange="window.location.href = 'test.php?Period=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
```

Comment: I have another similar question: <input name="date" id="datepicker" onchange="window.location.href = 'test.php?Date=' + document.getElementById("datepicker").value;"> It should send the value inside the input box but it doesn't send anything?

Comment: Can you help with this please?

Comment: Your code should work, did you test in console (ff/chrome) if that selector outputs anything ? document.getElementById("datepicker").value
Remember you should have <input id="datepicker" value="something" /> for this to work

Answer (score 1):

you can easily read the value when the select triggers the change event:

```
<select onchange="window.location.href = 'test.php?Period=' + this.value;">
</select>
```